# How do wave equations have an exponential solution involving wave vector and the propagation constant?

Tags: electromagnetism, photons, plasmon

I hope you all are doing well!

I was trying to derive the propagation constant for the wave vector of the surface plasmons. I have uploaded the document below, which is the following:

[Here , is the following document under consideration for the derivation for the surface plasmon wave vector derivation](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F0-387-37825-1_2.pdf)

if you just look above the equation (2.6a), they have replaced:$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} = -i\omega $$

and also , if we look below 2.6f we will have the following:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} = -i\beta  $$

I would like to know the reason for how we can replace these terms any particular reason for the consideration of angular frequency and imaginary i with a negative sign and an imaginary term with propagation constant.
Also , now if you can look at the equation 2.8 (c) in the document uploaded above:
for a wave equation for the following form given below:

$$ \frac{\partial^2 H_y}{\partial z^2} + (K_0^2\epsilon -\beta^2)H_y =0 $$

How can we have a solution of the form given below, is it a standard equation for all the homogeneous 2nd order differential wave equation form equations???

$$H_y(z) = Ae^{i\beta x}e^{-k_2 z}   $$

Can anyone please explain me the following reasons occurring here.

if any more information is required, please do let me know.

I am looking forward to hearing from you
Thank you
regards
Ketan

Answer (score 0):

So the two equation comes for the Fourier transformation. To get the angular response of a system, FT is very standard technique.
$$A(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int d\omega\ \exp(-i\omega t) \tilde{A}(\omega )$$
Taking derivative both sides
$$\frac{\partial A(t)}{\partial t}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int d\omega\ \exp(-i\omega) (-i\omega)\tilde{A}(\omega )$$
So without any loss of generality one can replace $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ with $-i\omega$, but you have to transform the function in Fourier space as well. Similarly for spatial derivative. **Note that this is a physicist proof. You can find more rigorous proof in many references.**

Coming to your solution to 2nd order differental equation, for partial double derivative in z, I can assume a solution of the form,
$$H_{y}(z)=g(x,y)e^{-k_2z}$$
where $k_2^2 = (K_0^2\epsilon - \beta^2)$. Also in the reference this solution is for the region $z>0$. For $z<0$, you need $e^{k_2z}$ so that the function is well defined at $\pm \infty$. So the Electric field becomes,
$$E_{y}(z)=cg(x,y)e^{-k_2z}$$
where $c$ is the constant factor mentioned in the reference. However, in the first line of page 23, it was assumed that $\vec{E}(x,y,z)=\vec{E}(z)e^{i\beta x}$. Comparing with the above equation, $g(x,y)$ must be of the form $e^{i\beta x}$. Therefore,
$$H_{y}(z)=A e^{i\beta x}e^{-k_2z}$$